# Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime error

Tags: azure

I am trying to run through the Excercise at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_vmrolelab_topic3) and am getting an error in Task 2 when trying to run Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime:

Add-PSSnapin : Cannot load Windows PowerShell snap-in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime because of the following error:

```
The Windows PowerShell snap-in module C:\Program Files\Windows Azure Integration Components\v1.6\Powershell\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Commands.dll does not have required Windows PowerShell snap-in strong name Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Commands, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
At line:1 char:13
+ Add-PSSnapin <<<<  Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSSnapIn
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand
```

All previous tasks have completed without issue and task 2, step 2 states that "the snap-in is installed with the integration components and provides access to the Windows Azure runtime environment" which was performed without issue in a previous Excercise and Task.  Has anyone run into this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to run this command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

This will allow us to run any plug-ins, even if the plug-in is not strong name signed. But be aware this may introduce security issues. So it is recommended to revert the execution policy after you finishes the tutorial.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted
```

You can also refer to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347628.aspx for more information

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: This didn't help, I receive the same error:

Add-PSSnapin : Cannot load Windows PowerShell snap-in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime because of the following er
ror: The Windows PowerShell snap-in module C:\Program Files\Windows Azure Integration Components\v1.6\Powershell\Micros
oft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Commands.dll does not have required Windows PowerShell snap-in strong name Microsoft.Wi
ndowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Commands, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.

Comment: PS C:\> get-executionpolicy -list
Scope            ExecutionPolicy
-----            ---------------
MachinePolicy    Undefined
UserPolicy       Undefined
Process          Unrestricted
CurrentUser      Unrestricted
LocalMachine     Unrestricted

Comment: Another possibility is you haven’t correctly installed the Windows Azure PowerShell plug-in. Please try to reinstall it. This thread may help: http://www.powershellcommunity.org/Forums/tabid/54/aft/860/Default.aspx.

Comment: You may also need to install a new version of PowerShell. We upgraded some internal cmdlets to use System.Management.Automation.dll from PowerShell 3 and someone had this issue until she upgraded to PS3. I had v4 but I needed to run the command in the answer.